# Javascript adding DIV's on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textfield with one "add more highlights" text link, what i need is when i click on each time on add link i should be able to display 3 div's one below the other.

Given my HTML code below;

```
<input size="20" id="high_light" type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="Highlights of this offer" /> 
 <span><a href="#" id="add"> + Add more highlights</a></span>
 <div id="highlight1" style="display:none;"><input class="word_count2" size="20" name="high_light2" id="high_light2" type="text" maxlength="30" /></div> 
<div id="highlight2" style="display:none;"><input class="word_count2" size="20" name="high_light2" id="high_light2" type="text" maxlength="30" /></div> 
<div id="highlight3" style="display:none;"><input class="word_count2" size="20" name="high_light2" id="high_light2" type="text" maxlength="30" /></div>
```

Thanks
Ajeesh

Comment: Would you want to add the DIVs below the existing ones you have in your example code, or are they examples of the type of DIVs you would want to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var count = 1;  
            $('#add').click(function(){
                if(count < 4){
                   $('body').append('<div id="highlight'+count+'"><input class="word_count2" size="20" name="high_light2" id="high_light2" type="text" maxlength="30" /></div> ');
                   if(count == 3){
                      $('#add').hide();
                   } 
                } else {
                   $('#add').hide();
                }
                count++;
            });

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Hello Naveen, Can we able to hide this Add link " <span><a href="#" id="add"> + Add more highlights</a></span>" after clicking showing the  3rd text box div? please help me. Thanks

Comment: Hello Naveen, you are really great it is working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Pure JS version:

```
<div id="divParent">
    <a onclick="createThreeDivs()">Click me!</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function createThreeDivs() {
  for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   var divText = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
   div.appendChild(divText);
   var divParent = document.getElementById("divParent");
   divParent.appendChild(div);
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: +1 but you need to remove the `<>` from the createElement call. Should be `document.createElement("div");`.

Comment: No problem :) also small typo in the function name `createtThreeDivs`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing it but here's something anyway -

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var $additional_div = $('<div style="display:none;"><input class="word_count2" size="20" name="high_light2" id="high_light2" type="text" maxlength="30" /></div>');
    $('#container_div').append($additional_div)
                       .append($additional_div)
                       .append($additional_div);
}
```

You'll have to do something about the additional div id's. Are they required? are you going to be repeating this?

Comment: `var $div = $('<div />')` and then append `$div` 3 times may be a little more readable? You decide :)

Comment: I think you're probably right Sam, I'll leave OP to make the change if desired.

Comment: Even though this will work, this would require jQuery the post is tagged as JavaScript.

Comment: whoops, I thought I'd searched jquery questions (must have clicked javascript)

Comment: Oh well there's a few pure js solutions already. I think I'll leave it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var clickEle  = document.getElementById("high_light1");
clickEle.onclick = function() {
      var html   = "<div></div><div></div><div></div>";
      var parEle = document.getElementById("container_div");
      parEle.innerHTML += html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#add").click(function(){
  $(this).after('<div><input type=text></div>');
  $(this).after('<div><input type=text></div>');
  $(this).after('<div><input type=text></div>');
```

})

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').bind('click', function(){
      for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        var highlightId = "highlight"+i;
        var highlightDiv = '<div id="'+highlightId+'" style="display:none;"><input class="word_count2" size="20" name="high_light2" id="high_light2" type="text" maxlength="30" /></div>';
        $('#highlightsContainer').append(highlightDiv);
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<input size="20" id="high_light" type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="Highlights of this offer" /> 
<span><a href="#" id="add"> + Add more highlights</a></span>
<div id="highlightsContainer"></div>
```